# C# & SQL Server realtime DML events

Tags: c#, sql-server, real-time, dml, extended-events

I have a requirement to generate DML events (insert, update, delete) from SQL Server to an external entity. I have tried implementing extended events using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.XELite` nuget package. But it does not provide the row data, but only the statement executed.

I have also seen the `fn_dblog` function to retrieve the data from transaction logs. But it seems too complicated.

Is there any other way to achieve this (without of course using triggers or any manual work like CDC)?

Comment: Change Data Capture. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, thank you for reply. Without using CDC (updated question)?

Comment: If you don't want to write code there are 3rd party products, like Striim, Qlik, GoldenGate, or Debezium.